# The girl broke into a trot and disappeared around the corner. (nuance of break into)

Tags: idioms-in-context

> The girl broke into a trot and disappeared around the corner.

As I know, 'break into' means 'invade' and what's the nuance of the 'broke into a trot'?

Does this mean the girl suddently and unexpectedly changed her action into a trot?

When do you use the expression 'break into sth'?

Comment: Where did you see this sentence? Source? A horse trots, the author is comparing the character's sudden change of movements to that of a horse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone 'breaks into' a run, a trot, a stream of curses, a scream, [a] song, etc, that mean they suddenly change from what they were doing, (e.g. standing till, walking, saying nothing, talking normally) to doing the action described.

John was walking slowly. When he heard ruffians behind him, he broke into a brisk run.

My mother was talking quietly with me until I mentioned the Prime Minister's name. The she broke into a stream of hideous curses.

Jane was humming the tune of 'Jerusalem'. Then she broke into song - 'And did those feet in ancient time Walk upon England's mountains green?'.

> Break into
>
> PHRASAL VERB
>
> If someone breaks into something they suddenly start doing it. For
> example if someone breaks into a run they suddenly start running, and
> if they break into song they suddenly start singing.
>
> The moment she was out of sight she broke into a run.
> Then, breaking into a smile, he said, 'I brought you something.'

[Break into (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/break-into)

Comment: +1 The definition at [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/break%20into) even includes the example, *// the horse breaks into a gallop*